# CppUnit : Not able to write test cases

Tags: c++, cppunit

I have written cppUnit codes in `testBMath.cc`. I am able to write test cases for first three functions which are add,subtract and multiply. But I am not able to write test cases for Divide and Swap.I don't know how to handle divide by zero in test cases and how to check that numbers are swapped or not in cppUnit test cases.

testMath.h

```
#ifndef TEST_MATH_H__
    #define TEST_MATH_H__
    class testMath
    {
    public:
    int Addition(int x, int y);
    int Multiply(int x, int y);
    int Subtraction(int x, int y);
    int Division(int x, int y);
    void swap(int &x, int &y);
    };
#endif
```

testMath.cc

```
    #include "testMath.h"

    int testMath::Addition(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x + y);
    }

    int testMath::Multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x * y);
    }

    int testMath::Subtraction(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x - y);
    }

    int testMath::Division(int x, int y)
    {
       if( b == 0 )
    {
          throw "Division by zero condition!";
    }
       return (a/b);
    }

    void swap(int &a, int &b)
    {
      int temp;

      temp = b;
      b   = a;
      a   = temp;   
    }
```

testBMath.cc

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <list>
    #include "cppunit/TestCase.h"
    #include "cppunit/TestFixture.h"
    #include "cppunit/ui/text/TextTestRunner.h"
    #include "cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h"
    #include "cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h"
    #include "cppunit/TestResult.h"
    #include "cppunit/TestResultCollector.h"
    #include "cppunit/TestRunner.h"
    #include "cppunit/BriefTestProgressListener.h"
    #include "cppunit/CompilerOutputter.h"
    #include "netinet/in.h"

    #include "testMath.h"

    using namespace CppUnit;
    using namespace std;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class testBMath : public CppUnit::TestFixture
    {
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(testBMath);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testAddition);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testMultiply);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testSubtraction);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testDivision);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testSwap);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

    public:
    void setUp(void);
    void tearDown(void);

    protected:
    void testAddition(void);
    void testMultiply(void);
    void testSubtraction(void);
    void testDivision(void);
    void testSwap(void);

    private:
    testMath *mTestObj;
    };

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void testBMath::setUp(void)
    {
    mTestObj = new testMath();
    }

    void testBMath::testAddition(void)
    {
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT(5 == mTestObj->Addition(2,3));
    }

    void testBMath::testMultiply(void)
    {
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT(6 == mTestObj->Multiply(2,3));
    }
    void testBMath::testSubtraction(void)
    {
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT(2 == mTestObj->Subtraction(5,3));
    }

    void testBMath::testDivision(void)
    {
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT(6 == mTestObj->Division(12,2));
    //But for divide by zero how should I write
    }

    void testBMath::testSwap(void)
    {
    //How should I check for swap
    }

    void testBMath::tearDown(void)
    {
    delete mTestObj;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION( testBMath );

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    // informs test-listener about testresults
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResult testresult;

    // register listener for collecting the test-results
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResultCollector collectedresults;
    testresult.addListener (&collectedresults);

    // register listener for per-test progress output
    CPPUNIT_NS::BriefTestProgressListener progress;

    testresult.addListener (&progress);

    // insert test-suite at test-runner by registry
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestRunner testrunner;

    testrunner.addTest (CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest ());

    testrunner.run(testresult);

    // output results in compiler-format
    CPPUNIT_NS::CompilerOutputter compileroutputter(&collectedresults, std::cerr);

    compileroutputter.write ();

    // return 0 if tests were successful
    return collectedresults.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestions, change exception from `const char*` to something more meaningful, like `std::runtime_error`:

```
int testMath::Division(int x, int y)
{
   if( b == 0 )
   {
      throw std::runtime_error("Division by zero condition!");
   }
   return (a/b);
}
```

Than the test's would look like:

```
void testBMath::testDivision(void)
{
   CPPUNIT_ASSERT(6 == mTestObj->Division(12,2));
   CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW(mTestObj->Division(12,0), std::runtime_error);
}

void testBMath::testSwap(void)
{
   int x = 2;
   int y = 3;
   mTestObj->swap(x, y);
   CPPUNIT_ASSERT(x == 3 && y == 2);
}
```

Comment: `testBMath.cc: In member function `void testBMath::testSwap()':

testBMath.cc:58: error: `myTestObj' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: I am getting this error, can you tell me what to do.

Comment: I made a typo, it should be `mTestObj` of course. I edited the post also.

Comment: Its corrected thanks,but i am getting another error last one
`In function `testBMath::testSwap()':
/home5/e2sn7cy/unittest/testBMath.cc:58: undefined reference to `testMath::Swap(int, int)'
`

Comment: in your file *testMath.cc* edit the line `void swap(int &a, int &b)` to `void testMath::swap(int &a, int &b)`

Comment: Thanks Sir, thanks a lot for your precious time its working fine now.